# How to restrict entry of duplicate rows based on some columns in SharePoint List (Office 365)?

Tags: sharepoint, office365, sharepoint-list

I have a SharePoint list (Office 365). I want to restrict the user to be not able to enter duplicate rows based on some columns.
For Ex : [image]
 in case of this table i want to restrict duplicated entry based on columns ColA & colB. Is there any validation setting i can implement for the SharePoint List.

Comment: If my reply helps you, please mark the reply as answer, it will make others who stuck with the similar issue easier to search for valid solutions in this forum.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I already went through the links but it doesn't help my problem. My list is in a SharePoint Online list (Office 365). I have to use the default options only.

Comment: Please see the link below :[Unique Entries Based on Multiple Columns in Sharepoint List](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1205585/Unique-Entries-Based-on-Multiple-Columns-in-Sharep)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately we don't have any default option from column such as setting 2 columns and force it as two unique columns.

But we can achieve this by using only info-path form.

For more information, please review the following link:

[Prevention of duplicate entries based on two or more columns in a SharePoint list](https://salnikan.wordpress.com/2011/07/26/prevention-of-duplicate-entries-based-on-two-or-more-columns-in-a-sharepoint-list/)

[Can I prevent duplicates to a SP2013 list with a validation formula?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/168191/can-i-prevent-duplicates-to-a-sp2013-list-with-a-validation-formula)

Hope that helps.